# Calculate time elapsed between cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to calculate the time elapsed (passed) between two reoccurring events. My excel sheet looks like this.

```
  Cell A    Cell B      Cell C
1 14-Aug-17 8:59:13 PM  Quota recovery
2 14-Aug-17 8:56:12 PM  Quota violation
3 14-Aug-17 6:00:12 AM  Quota recovery
4 14-Aug-17 5:36:12 AM  Quota violation
5 14-Aug-17 4:00:12 AM  Quota recovery
6 14-Aug-17 3:51:12 AM  Quota violation
```

Something simple as B1-B2 will give me the desired result for one entry but I have close to a thousands cells that I need to perform the same calculation on.

Is it possible to automatically calculate and add up to time between each violation and recovery for the whole excel sheet to give me the total amount of time the quota was violated?

Comment: Exactly the reply I needed and in less than one minute. You Sir, deserve a beer :D

I did make one small change, I don't think a helper column is necessary.


    =SUMIF(C:C,"Quota recovery",B:B)-SUMIF(C:C,"Quota violation",B:B)


Seems to give me the correct results. It might not work perfectly if a violation flows over into the next day but I can live with that for now.

Edit: No idea why I can't do a code block in comments...

Comment: Because comments are for comments, not for code. Use the back tick to the left of the 1 key on the keyboard for very short code one-liners in comments `like this`. If you follow the help link that appears when you type a comment, you can learn more about formatting in comments. Worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

```
=sumproduct(((A1:A6)+(B1:B6))*(C1:C6="Quota recovery"))-sumproduct(((A1:A6)+(B1:B6))*(C1:C6="Quota violation"))
```

Similar to pnuts comment, but using an array function and bypassing the helper cell.  Since it an array like formula, make sure to define your range to what you need.